# XmlHttpRequest - send() with post seems to not work

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying the following :

```
<html>

<script src ="myscript.js" type = "text/javascript">
// in this file i have the foo functions defined... 
</script>

<!--- here the page is defined -->
<form action = "some.php" method = "post">
<input type = "submit" name ="exec" value = "EX" style="width:40px" id = "EX" onClick="foo();"> 
</html>
```

Now, in myscript.js :

```
function foo() {
    var req;
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", "mydomain.name/hello.php", false);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // ldt is a successfully defined string, 
    // i am not showing the complete function, but an alert here 
    // showes that ldt is successfully defined
    req.send(ldt);

    alert("sent");
    alert(req.status);
    if(req.status == 200)
    {
        var lddata = req.responseText;
        alert(lddata);
    }
}
```

Not that in my javascript, I have called hello.php, while the form in the initial htmp goes to a different file : some.php.

The file hello.php just spits "hello world" , and nothing else - at this moment, nothing is doe with the post variables.

Now, I would expect that until req.send() recieves a response, it javascript wont execute any futher, and before some.php is loaded, i will at least be alerted about the state of req.

However, in firefox (all files are being excuted from a local apache server, besides for hello.php, which is in mydomain.name. I have CORS enabled by default.), before I get to know the status of req via an alert, the next page, some.php is loaded.

What is wrong?

PS: there are some questions in the similar topic in SO, but i did not seem to have made any progress with them.

EDIT: as mentioned in the comment : this is the plan

1. Click on the "EX" button, in the html file at the begining, causes the onClick function foo() to get activated.
2. foo() does the XmlHttpRequest() to load a response from hello.php somewhere else (mydomain.name)
3. Then foo() alos sets the value of an hidden input element
4. Then since EX is a submit button, the form submits everything (including the newly set hidden element) to some.php, which is in the same server.

Edit 2: Also tried with

```
req.open("POST", "http://mydomain.name/hello.php", false);
```

as mentioned in a comment, did not work either.

Comment: You should show the complete ajax code, now it is not clear what is called when.

Comment: foo simply defines ldt, and then feeds ldata to a hidden element. The form from the first html file calles "some.php", when the submit button EX is called. However, the submit button EX (see the first html) also has an onclick method defined on it, which loads the response from hello.php

Comment: your url is incorrect `mydomain.name/hello.php` is going to be a request BACK to the server this page was loaded from, which'd be more like `http://example.com/mydomain.name/hello.php`. If you want to really do a cross-site request, it'd have to be `http://mydomain.name/hello.php`.

Comment: tried that with a http://mydomain.name/hello.php too. Same outcome, Did not realize that I needed to mention it. Sorry :(

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: Your form submit will not include the new value of the hidden button; your form will submit right after the start of the ajax call but before the results are back.

Comment: Thank you for the head up. It was indeed a CORS error. I will reset the permissions.